# how to display multiple polylines from directions in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to draw multiple polylines on the google map, for multiple routes.
for this i am using `google.maps.DirectionsService`

```
function drawPolyline(source,destination,waypoints){
        // show route between the points
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
        {
            suppressMarkers: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var request = {
            origin:source, 
            destination:destination,
            waypoints:waypoints,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            }
        });

      }
```

but when i call this method multiple times, only last polyline is appearing.
and i want different colors for different polylines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directions lets you inspect the route:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/directions.html#InspectingResults

The DirectionsResult object has and array of routes[], which allows you to get a set of encoded polylines that makes up the route:

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                myRoutes[]=response.routes[];

            }
```

You can use the routes[] array to construct Polyline overlays as Scottux mentioned.

Comment: Actually this is wrong. The "routes" array contain different options for the same route, not different legs. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsResults): "Generally, only one route is returned for any given request, unless the request's provideRouteAlternatives field is set to true, in which, multiple routes may be returned.".
Curently it's not possible to customize legs when using the DirectionsRenderer, you have to build separated Polylines for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a polyline for each, not a directions renderer.

```
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({clickable:true,map:map,path:"some lat,lngs"});
```

Please look at the api here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polyline
Options are listed here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#PolylineOptions

The DirectionsRenderer isn't very flexible for drawing lines, it is simply a helper for simple direction functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually instantiate multiple `DirectionsRenderer` and set them all to the same map and they will all render on the same map

[image]